# using MediaElement play video issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, video, mediaelement

I am using the popular sl2videoplayer from codeplex to play video, and everything is fine when I play remote video on an IIS web server. Sl2videoplayer could be found here, http://www.codeplex.com/sl2videoplayer

But when I open the default.html locally from disk (double click default.html to open in IE), there is error message in IE like this (there is a warning sign in IE at the left bottom corner, please refers to the below screen snapshot). There is no code change in sl2videoplayer except that I change the media file to Output.wmv as shown below. Any ideas what is wrong? The effect I want to achieve is I want to play local file using the silverlight player without connecting to server (when disconnected from internet), could we do that using Siverlight.

default.html I am using (I copied Output.wmv into ClientBin directory, and VideoPlayer.xap resides in the same directory)

```
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
  <object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="500" height="240">
   <param name="source" value="ClientBin/VideoPlayer.xap"/>
   <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
   <param name="background" value="white" />
   <param name="initParams" value="cc=true,markers=true,markerpath=markers_movie21.xml,m=Output.wmv" />
   <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=115261" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
   </a>
  </object>
  <iframe style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe>
    </div>
```

Error message in IE and related screen snapshot,

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; CIBA; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 10 Jul 2009 06:20:19 UTC


Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at VideoPlayer.App.Application_UnhandledException(Object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(Exception e)
   at MS.Internal.Error.GetXresultForUserException(Exception ex)     

Line: 53
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Test/sl2videoplayer/VideoPlayerWeb/default.html
```

Screen snapshot in IE,

http://i31.tinypic.com/xgh84i.jpg

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it's complaining that one of the paths provided is not a fully valid URI. A relative one should be fine, though.

I'm not sure what line 53 is, but it is complaining that the problem is present at character 13 in that line. Do you have the markers_movie21.xml you refer to with the "markerpath" attribute? That might be part of your problem - try removing the attribute if you don't have the file and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks ravuya, you are so cool! After removing markerpath=markers_movie21.xml, it works. One more question, how do you know it is markers_movie21.xml issue?

Comment: My guess: it was complaining about a URI path being incorrect, and you said you had changed one of the attributes (m) but you didn't say anything about the other one (markerpath).

I'm glad it worked. Please don't forget to mark my reply as an answer. :)